# Teamcity - parametrized builds

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity, parameterized

Is there any way to configure parametrized builds in team city?

I need to pass a few parameters before actually triggering the build. I have multiple releases for a project and I need to pass the release version manually each time my build fires (It's not an CI Build)

I would then use this release version in my build accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really don't want to use TeamCity to manage your version numbers then one option is to create a `BuildVersion` (or whatever you want to call it) [build parameter](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Build+Parameters) for your configuration.

You then need to manually define the version each time you trigger a build; you can do this by clicking the [custom build button](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Triggering+a+Custom+Build) and entering the version against the parameter in the subsequent dialog.

You can then use the `BuildVersion` property in your script.

This, however, does not stop people from executing the build without defining that parameter though (may cause some mayhem).